# How to select boolean value with Cypress select method without type error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, cypress

I'm trying to write cypress test where if user selects True then font size changes. The code below works if I change the type to string, but fails on boolean with following type error: "Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | (string | number)[]"

```
setActive: (value: boolean): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery> => 
  cy.get('#control-active').select(value)
```

I want this setActive method to be used in following test scenario

```
it('active can be set', () => {
  labelControls.setActive(true);
  getLabel().should('have.css', 'font-size', '14px');
```

I checked cypress document and it seems "select" does not support boolean. Is there a way where I can get "select" to accept boolean value as well?

Comment: What are your dropdown values ?

Comment: true/false, it's boolean. I'm trying to test my react component <Label active={true}></Label>

Comment: How about instead of passing a boolean value you pass true as string `labelControls.setActive('true')` and also change this to string `setActive: (value: string)`

Comment: Nope, error is located at select(value). Updating bottom code doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The `.select()` command is for dropdowns, but if your values are true/false then you have a checkbox.

Cypress provides `.check()` and `.uncheck()`

```js
setActive: (value: boolean): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery> => 
  if (value) {
    cy.get('#control-active').check()
  } else {
    cy.get('#control-active').uncheck()
  }
```

I'm making a guess here, it would help confirm if you can post the DOM.